# Getting the height of a Cloudinary Image Object in Django

Tags: python, django, cloudinary

in my models, I have the following code:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    display_picture = CloudinaryField('Display Picture')
```

It allows me to upload images directly to Cloudinary using a simple Django form. However, I need to get the height of these images. How exactly do I do this? Is there a built-in method that I can call that returns the height? Thanks.

Comment: did you try to call it like: -- instance.display_picture.height --  ??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried taking a look at the return value of the upload?
An upload API call to Cloudinary returns a Hash with the resource content detail such as height.